# Как вывести результат запроса?

Tags: php, sql-server, mysql

Возникла проблема по выводу результата запроса при помощи php. Суть проблемы в том, что происходит наложение одних данных другими Как то так, не знаю как по другому написать.Подробнее описано с примерами, ниже:

Написал запрос MSSQL, проверил его в самой СУБД, отрабатывает отлично и не происходит наложение.Ниже сам запрос:

```
SELECT  a1.INCIDENT_ID, 
        dateadd(hour,8,c1.OPEN_TIME),
        a1.BRIEF_DESCRIPTION,
        a1.ACTION, 
        a1.NUMBER, 
        a1.CATEGORY, 
        dateadd(hour,8,c1.UPDATE_TIME),
        a1.ASSIGNMENT,
        a1.STATUS, 
        a1.CLOSE_TIME, 
        a1.CLOSED_BY,
        a1.VENDOR, 
        a1.REFERENCE_NO, 
        a1.CAUSE_CODE, 
        a1.RESOLUTION_CODE, 
        a1.RESOLUTION, 
        a1.ASSIGNEE_NAME, 
        a1.UPDATE_ACTION, 
        a1.ACTOR,
        a1.OPEN_GROUP,
        a1.CLOSING_COMMENTS,
        a1.UPDATED_BY,
        a1.PROBLEM_STATUS,
        a1.SUBCATEGORY,
        a1.SYSMODUSER,
        b1.OPER_BIZDESC,
        b1.CALLBACK_CONTACT_DEPT,
        b1.CALLBACK_CONTACT,
        c1.ALTERNATE_CONTACT,
        d1.CONTACT_PHONE,
            d1.FULL_NAME,
            e1.CONTACT_PHONE,
            e1.FULL_NAME

FROM
        PROBSUMMARYM1 a1
INNER JOIN
        PROBSUMMARYM2 b1 ON a1.NUMBER=b1.NUMBER
INNER JOIN
        INCIDENTSM1 c1 ON a1.INCIDENT_ID=c1.INCIDENT_ID
INNER JOIN
        CONTCTSM1 d1 ON d1.CONTACT_NAME=c1.ALTERNATE_CONTACT
INNER JOIN
        CONTCTSM1 e1 ON a1.ASIGNMENT=e1.OPERATOR_ID
WHERE
        a1.INCIDENT_ID LIKE 'IM10234' or a1.NUMBER LIKE 'IM10234'
ORDER BY 
        a1.INCIDENT_ID DESC
```

Проблема возникает при выводе результата при помощи php. Затык именно вот в этом месте:

```
INNER JOIN
            CONTCTSM1 d1 ON d1.CONTACT_NAME=c1.ALTERNATE_CONTACT
INNER JOIN
            CONTCTSM1 e1 ON a1.ASIGNMENT=e1.OPERATOR_ID
```

Выводиться результат по последнему объединению.

Может как то можно разбить на два запроса или один запрос вложить в цикл другого? Как это сделать, что то понять не могу. Сам код php, который выводит информацию без объединения с "e1" с "d1" отрабатывает отлично:

```
<?php include 'templates/header.php'; ?>
<body>
<?php
//получаем данные через $_POST
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    // подключаемся к базе
    include('inc/db.php');
    $db = new db();

    $word =$_POST['search'];
    // Строим запрос

    $sql = "SELECT  a1.INCIDENT_ID, 
        c1.OPEN_TIME,
        a1.BRIEF_DESCRIPTION,
        a1.ACTION, 
        a1.NUMBER, 
        a1.CATEGORY, 
        c1.UPDATE_TIME,
        a1.ASSIGNMENT,
        a1.STATUS, 
        a1.CLOSE_TIME, 
        a1.CLOSED_BY,
        a1.VENDOR, 
        a1.REFERENCE_NO, 
        a1.CAUSE_CODE, 
        a1.RESOLUTION_CODE, 
        a1.RESOLUTION, 
        a1.ASSIGNEE_NAME, 
        a1.UPDATE_ACTION, 
        a1.ACTOR,
        a1.OPEN_GROUP,
        a1.CLOSING_COMMENTS,
        a1.UPDATED_BY,
        a1.PROBLEM_STATUS,
        a1.SUBCATEGORY,
        a1.SYSMODUSER,
        b1.OPER_BIZDESC,
        b1.CALLBACK_CONTACT_DEPT,
        b1.CALLBACK_CONTACT,
        c1.ALTERNATE_CONTACT,
        d1.CONTACT_PHONE,
        d1.FULL_NAME

FROM
        PROBSUMMARYM1 a1
INNER JOIN
        PROBSUMMARYM2 b1 ON a1.NUMBER=b1.NUMBER
INNER JOIN
        INCIDENTSM1 c1 ON a1.INCIDENT_ID=c1.INCIDENT_ID
INNER JOIN
        CONTCTSM1 d1 ON d1.CONTACT_NAME=c1.ALTERNATE_CONTACT
WHERE
        a1.INCIDENT_ID LIKE '%" . $word . "%' or a1.NUMBER LIKE '%" . $word . "%'";

?>
    <div id="wrapper">
       <?php include 'templates/menu.php'; ?>  
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">Поиск по номеру обращения и инциденту в УФК по Красноярскому краю V.0.2</h1>
                    <h4>Введите номер обращения или инцидента:</h4>                 
                    <form method="post" action="do_search.php">
                    <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                            <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите номер обращения, например: SD1000969. Для поиска нажмите Enter...">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </span>

                    </div>
                    </form>
                    <br>
                            <!-- /input-group -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            Вы искали: <b><?php echo $_POST['search'] ?></b><br>
                            <!--<a class="btn btn-default" title="Выгрузить данные в Excel" type="button" href="test.php?test=<?php echo $_POST['search'] ?>"/>
                                    <i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i>Выгрузка данных в Excel
                            </a> -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>№</th>
                                            <th>Номер обращения</th>
                                            <th>Номер инцидента</th>
                                            <th>Статус</th>
                                            <th>Дата создания</th>
                                            <th>Дата закрытия</th>
                                            <th>Контактное лицо</th>
                                            <th>Назначенный</th>
                                            <th>Краткое описание проблемы</th>

                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
<?  
    // Переменные
    $sent = 'По обращению:';
    $im_w_sent = iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251", $sent);
    // Получаем результаты
    $row = $db->select_list($sql);
    if(count($row)) {
        $end_result = '';
        foreach($row as $r) {
            // Контактная информация о специалисте\

            //определение даты, создание нового формата
            $counter++;
            $date = new DateTime ($r['OPEN_TIME']);
            $date2 = new DateTime ($r['CLOSE_TIME']);

            $result1         .= '<tr class="odd gradeX">'
            . '<td>' . $counter . '</td>'
            . '<td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#' . $r['INCIDENT_ID'] . '">' . $r['INCIDENT_ID'] . '</button>
            <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                            <!-- Modal -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="'
            . $r['INCIDENT_ID']  
            . '" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"> Информация по обращению:&nbsp' 
            . $r['INCIDENT_ID']             
            . '</h4></div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="alert alert-success">'
            . 'Статус:&nbsp'
            . $r['STATUS'] 
            . '</div></div>
                        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <!-- Nav tabs -->
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#home-'
            . $r['INCIDENT_ID'] 
            .'" data-toggle="tab">Информация</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#profile-'
            . $r['INCIDENT_ID'] 
            .'" data-toggle="tab">Описание проблемы</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#messages-'
            . $r['INCIDENT_ID'] 
            .'" data-toggle="tab">Решение</a>
                                </li> 
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#active-'
            . $r['INCIDENT_ID'] 
            .'" data-toggle="tab">Активность</a>
                                </li> 
                            </ul>

                            <!-- Tab panes -->
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home-'
            . $r['INCIDENT_ID'] 
            .'">
                                    </br>
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Контактное лицо</th>
                                            <th>Контакты</th>                                                                                       
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                    <td>
                                    <p>'
                . "".iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$r['FULL_NAME']).""
                . '</p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                    <p>'
                . "".iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$r['CONTACT_PHONE']).""
                . '</p>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                    </table>                                    
                                    </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile-'
            . $r['INCIDENT_ID'] 
            .'">
                                    </br>
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                    <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                    <td><b>Краткое описание проблемы:</b></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                    <td><p>'
            . "".iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$r['BRIEF_DESCRIPTION']).""
            . '</p>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                    <td>
                                    <b>Полное описание проблемы:</b>
                                    </td>
                                    <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                    <td>
                                    <p>'
            . "".iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$r['ACTION']).""
            . '</p>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>                                    
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="messages-'
            . $r['INCIDENT_ID'] 
            .'">
                                    </br>
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                    <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                    <td>
                                    <b>Код закрытия:</b>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="odd gradeX">                                 
                                    <td>
                                    <p>'
            . "".iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$r['CAUSE_CODE']).""
            . '</p>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                    <td>
                                    <b>Полное описание решения:</b>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                    <td>
                                    <p>'
            . "".iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$r['RESOLUTION']).""
            . '</p>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="active-'
            . $r['INCIDENT_ID'] 
            .'">                    
                                    </br>
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                    <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                    <td>
                                    <p>'
            . "".iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$r['UPDATE_ACTION']).""
            . '</p>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-body -->

                    <!-- /.panel -->

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>                                            
                                            <a class="btn btn-primary" title="Выгрузить данные в Excel" type="button" href="test.php?test='
            . $r['INCIDENT_ID'] 
            . '"/>
                                    <i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i>Выгрузка данных в Excel v.0.1
                                            </a>
                                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-social btn-twitter" href="mailto:' 
            . $r['ASSIGNEE_NAME'] 
            . '@mail.ru?subject=' 
            . $sent . $r['INCIDENT_ID'] 
            . ' - ' . $r['NUMBER'] 
            . ' " title="Написать на электронный адрес спициалисту"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>' 
            . $r['ASSIGNEE_NAME'] . '</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.modal -->
                        </div>
            <!-- .panel-body --></td>'          
            . '<td>' . $r['NUMBER'] . '</td>'
            . '<td>' . $r['STATUS'] . '</td>'
            . '<td>' . $date->format('d.m.Y H:i:s') . '</td>'
            . '<td>' . $date2->format('d.m.Y H:i:s') . '</td>'
            . '<td>' . "".iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$r['FULL_NAME'])."" .'</td>'
            . '<td><a class="btn btn-primary btn-social btn-twitter" href="mailto:' . $r['ASSIGNEE_NAME'] . '@mail.ru?subject=' . $sent . $r['INCIDENT_ID'] . ' - ' . $r['NUMBER'] . ' " title="Написать на электронный адрес спициалисту"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>' . $r['ASSIGNEE_NAME'] . '</a></td>' 
            . '<td>' . "".iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$r['BRIEF_DESCRIPTION'])."" .'</td>'

            . '</tr>';

            $end_result = $result1;

        }
        echo $end_result;
?>

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.table-responsive -->

                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <?php
    } else {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">По вашему запросу ничего не найдено.</div>';
    }

} 
?>

    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- Core Scripts - Include with every page -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>

    <!-- Page-Level Plugin Scripts - Tables -->
    <script src="js/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>

    <!-- SB Admin Scripts - Include with every page -->
    <script src="js/sb-admin.js"></script>

    <!-- Page-Level Demo Scripts - Tables - Use for reference -->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dataTables-example').dataTable();
    });

    // tooltip demo
    $('.tooltip-demo').tooltip({
        selector: "[data-toggle=tooltip]",
        container: "body"
    })

    // popover demo
    $("[data-toggle=popover]")
        .popover()
    </script>
    <!-- Page-Level Demo Scripts - Blank - Use for reference -->

</body>

</html>
```

Прошу помочь разобраться в том как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: @intertex

    // никогда не доверяйте входящим данным! Фильтруйте всё!
    $word =$_POST['search'];

Данные не фильтруются, и этот код представляет собой яркий пример SQL injection-уязвимого кода

Comment: не дописал данный кусок, хочу вынести его отдельно. 
интересует проблема именно с выводом данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте псевдонимы полей:

```
e1.CONTACT_PHONE as CONTACT_PHONE_e, e1.FULL_NAME as FULL_NAME_e
```

Comment: используя псевдонимы, у меня ответ возвращается пустой.
пробовал и в MSSQL прогнать запрос и через написанное приложение.

Comment: @intertex, значит написанное выше утверждение о том, что в студии работает отлично, не верно - псевдонимы столбцов влияют на имена полей, а не на процесс их получения. Проверьте также, что в своем коде вы обращаетесь к ним по измененным именам.

Comment: @maxleo, кстати, убрав условие where запрос отработал, при компиляции запроса ошибок нет с where...

Comment: @intertex, видимо у вас нет запрошенных данных. Это нормально. 
И вообще, используйте сохраненные процедуры.

Comment: извиняюсь, структура базы огромная, не правильно поле определил. все работает спасибо. 
А про сохраненные процедуры в MSSQL?

Comment: Почитайте справку на предмет create procedure. При обращении к серверу общайтесь исключительно через вызовы процедур, никаких сочинений текстов запросов внутри приложения - все обращения к серверу должны иметь смысл, так что процедур будет не слишком много, а в самый раз.